# building class that inherits pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to write a class that inherits pandas' `DataFrame` class for some custom data that I am working on.

```
class EquityDataFrame(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        DataFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def myfunc1(self,...)
        ... # does something

    def myfunc2(self, ...)
        ... # does something
```

In PyCharm, I get the following warning for the name of the class `EquityDataFrame`:

```
Class EquityDataFrame must implement all abstract methods 

This inspection detects when there aren't all abstract properties/methods defined in the subclass
```

I tried googling, but I couldn't find a useful description of this warning. Can someone help me what this warning means?

Comment: would be helpful to check if this error is specific to pycharm, or if you also get some related error if you try to run your program independently

Comment: Could not replicate this problem under either Python 2 or Python 3. Maybe other parts of your code trigger the problem, but it's not just this straightforward subclassing of `DataFrame`.

Comment: yes, I found a few more posts on SO about subclassing `DataFrame`. It might be due to that

Comment: @uday, did you find why this has been happened? I have same warning in my inherited class in python 2.7 and I did not find how can I make this correct.

Comment: @SencerH., no i did not. but i ended up writing my own DataFrame class which has a Pandas DataFrame as a field, and then in the new class I overwrote a lot of the Pandas functionality to customize it to something similar to how R works (and made it a bit faster in some areas). this way my class can be inherited and i even wrote a few child classes which inherit this class and have additional custom functionality depending upon the needs. took me quite a while. if you want to do the same, you have write your own `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__dir__`, `__getattr__` methods, etc.

Answer (score 3):

After looking for 6 years, pylint gave me the answer :
`[W0223(abstract-method), CustomDataFrame] Method '_constructor_expanddim' is abstract in class 'DataFrame' but is not overridden`

And indeed implementing

```
@property
def _constructor_expanddim(self) -> Type["CustomDataFrame"]:
    raise NotImplementedError("Not supported for CustomDataFrames!")
```

made the warning disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the below

```
import pandas as pd

class MyDataframe(pd.DataFrame):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyDataframe, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

@property
def function_1(self, x):


@property
def function_2(self):
```

Answer (score 0):

## Create a pandas Dataframe-like class that is chainable

```
from pandas import DataFrame

class PrepPandas(DataFrame):
  """Class that inherits from pandas.DataFrame then customizes it with additonal methods."""
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  @property
  def _constructor(self):
      """
      Creates a self object that is basically a pandas.Dataframe.
      self is a dataframe-like object inherited from pandas.DataFrame
      self behaves like a dataframe + new custom attributes and methods.
      """
      return PrepPandas

  def mult2(self):
    """
    Method to demo chanining multiple function calls. Ex: pdf.mult2().mult2()
    
    Example:
      pdf = PrepPandas({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
      print(pdf, pdf.mult2(),  pdf.mult2().mult2(), pdf.__class__, pdf.mult2().__class__)
    """
    return self * 2
```

## Usage Example

```
pdf = PrepPandas({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})  # Creates a pandas df.
pdf, pdf.mult2(),  pdf.mult2().mult2(), pdf.__class__, pdf.mult2().__class__   #  Adds a cutom mult2 function to the pdf.
```

## Output:

```
Out[5]: 
 (   
    a  b
 0  1  4
 1  2  5
 2  3  6,
    a   b
 0  2   8
 1  4  10
 2  6  12,
     a   b
 0   4  16
 1   8  20
 2  12  24,
 __main__.PrepPandas,
 __main__.PrepPandas
 )
```